# JSONP - Error 403 - Forbidden on Remote Server

Tags: php, rss, jsonp

I'm having an issue. I've been trying for 2 days to solve but until now I didn't have success :

**The Problem :**

I have a RSS Parser that **is fully functional on Localhost** but on **Hostgator** domain it does not allow to make request. Is there something else I can do?

I already tried **headers** :

```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
  header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Changed **file permissions** on the server, changed **.htaccess**  *( same headers above and other more )* and then, I came here : )

Any of you had this problem ? Thanks already !

[Pastebin of the PHP AJAX_getNews](http://pastebin.com/Et8dHfr1)

[Pastebin of the News class](http://pastebin.com/dTx6nzhs)

Edit: Actually it is  forbidden to me to even access the file directly, ajax calls returns forbidden also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean, it doesn't allow you to make the request?  What actual error are you getting?

What file permissions did you give it?  People tend to put 777 permissions on PHP files, thinking of mod_php setups, but HostGator's suPHP actually refuses to run in this case.  IIRC neither the .php file nor any directory in its path can be group- or world- writeable.

Comment: Julian,  Sorry about the delay  ! Yeah ! I put 777 permission on the files thinking it would be better, I'll post a screenshot

https://www.dropbox.com/s/csf1wncsxbr29jo/2014-04-20%2015_28_08-403%20-%20FORBIDDEN.png